# ptvsd: signal only works in main thread. Trying to configure vscode debugging of Flask app in Docker container

Tags: python, docker, flask, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to configure debugger for dockerized Flask application on VSCode. In order to do that, I've attached ptvsd to my app and exposed its port.

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)

if app.debug:
   print("attaching ptvsd")
   import ptvsd
   ptvsd.enable_attach(address = ('0.0.0.0', 3000), redirect_output=True)
   ptvsd.wait_for_attach()
   ptvsd.break_into_debugger()
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3

ENV FLASK_APP app/main.py

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0" ]
```

And command used to run container:

```
docker run -it --rm -p 5000:5000 -p 3000:3000 -e FLASK_ENV=development webserver
```

No error is shown by default after running container. When I try to attach debugger from vscode on port 3000, nothing happens. When I open any page of my app in web browser, this message appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/src/app/app/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    ptvsd.enable_attach(address = ('0.0.0.0', 3000), redirect_output=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ptvsd/attach_server.py", line 101, in enable_attach
    ptvsd_enable_attach(address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ptvsd/_remote.py", line 64, in enable_attach
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ptvsd/pydevd_hooks.py", line 128, in install
    daemon = Daemon(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ptvsd/daemon.py", line 503, in __init__
    super(Daemon, self).__init__(wait_for_user, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ptvsd/daemon.py", line 100, in __init__
    self._install_exit_handlers()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ptvsd/daemon.py", line 425, in _install_exit_handlers
    self._exithandlers.install()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ptvsd/exit_handlers.py", line 62, in install
    self._install_signal_handler()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ptvsd/exit_handlers.py", line 103, in _install_signal_handler
    orig[sig] = signal.signal(sig, self._signal_handler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/signal.py", line 47, in signal
    handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
```

Can someone explain me a meaning of error message? What is possible fix for that problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured that out thanks to [this repo](https://github.com/peterrus/flask-docker-debugging-vscode-example). In short, PTVSD is not compatible with Flask's "auto reload" feature. It needs to be disabled.

Ideally, I would like to keep both of those features (debugger and auto-reload) enabled, I haven't managed to that yet. Here is my temporary workaround.

I've created `docker-compose.yml` file. It's not necessary, but simplified process of starting server.

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "3000:3000"
    environment: 
      - FLASK_ENV=${FLASK_ENV}
    volumes:
      - .:/server_apps/webserver
```

Then I've created `docker-compose.debugger.yml`.

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    # Replace default run function
    # --no-reload is necessary to run PTVSD debugger
    command: ["flask", "run", "--no-reload"]
```

Which replaces default run command with another, having `--no-reload` argument.

Now, when I'm developing my app, I'm using

```
$ docker-compose up
```

which deploys default config (`docker-compose.yml`) auto-reloading app on every code change. When something's wrong and I want to use debugger I type

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.debugger.yml up
```

Comment: Support for auto-reload in the debugger is being worked on and should hopefully be available in the near future. Keep an eye on our release posts at https://aka.ms/pythonblog to know when it comes out.